# How to create a Symfony form that has a nested form for each active user in the database?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create an admin page for a sports club website so that each month, the admin user can generate new invoices (<kbd>Invoice</kbd> entity) for all active members (<kbd>Member</kbd> entity) of the club.

I'm trying to create the form so that I have one row for each member pre-populated with their standard monthly fee and the current date (both of which can be changed for individual member entries if needed):

[image: Diagram of forms required]

I have tried just about everything I can think of to get this working in a form but so far I've had no success. Below is the code as it currently stands but this gives me an individual form for just the last member....any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be very welcome - thanks in advance!

**Entities (Member and Invoice):**

```
class Member
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Invoice", mappedBy="member_id")
     */
    protected $invoice_ids;

    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $familyname;

    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $active = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2)
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Error")
     */
    protected $defaultinvoiceamount;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->invoice_ids        = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function FullName()
    {
        return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->familyname;
    }
}


class Invoice
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Member", inversedBy="invoice_ids")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id",     referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $member_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2)
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Error")
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    protected $invoicedate;


    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    protected $createdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="text", nullable=True)
     */
    protected $comments;

}
```

**FormType:**

```
class InvoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('member_id', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Member',
                    'choice_label' => 'FullName',
                    'attr' => array(
                         'readonly' => 'readonly'
                    )
                )
            )

            ->add('invoicedate', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'data' => new \DateTime('now'),
                'format' => 'dd/MMM/yyyy',
                'label' => 'Date of invoice',
            ))

            ->add('createdate', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'data' => new \DateTime('now'),
                'format' => 'dd/MMM/yyyy',
                'label' => 'Date invoice recorded in database',
                'disabled' => 'true'
            ))

            ->add('amount', MoneyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Amount',
            ))

            ->add('comments')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Invoice',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'invoice';
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
class MemberRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
     */
    public function findAllActiveMembers()
    {

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery
            (
                'SELECT m
                 FROM AppBundle:Member m
                 WHERE m.active= :active
                 ORDER BY m.surname, m.firstname'
            )
            ->setParameter('active' ,true)
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

**The Controller:**

```
/** 
 * @Route("/batchinvoices"  ,name="batchinvoices")
 */
public function newBatchInvoicesAction(Request $request)
{
    $members = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')->findAllActiveMembers(); 

    foreach ($members as $member) {
        $invoices = new Invoice();
        $invoices->setMemberId($member);
        $form=$this->createForm(InvoiceType::class, $invoices);
    }

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && ($form->isValid())) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($invoices);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('invoices_added');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/batchinvoices.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: To use fullName, create a public function in your entity called fullName and let it "rsturn $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->surname; ". You can in your twig code call {{ entity.getFullname() }}

Comment: Have you look at the documentation entry [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)? I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @Onema - yes I've been going through this several times but the CollectionType doesn't seem to right in this case as I want multiple instances of the whole form and not just a drop down or tags generated

Comment: The [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) 'is used to render a "collection" of some field or form.' I know is kind of long, but go through the whole tutorial, by the end you will be able to use what you learned in your own site. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are only getting the last entry in the form is that you are continually overwriting your own variables.  Take a look at this code specifically:

```
foreach ($members as $member) {
    $invoices = new Invoice();
    $invoices->setMemberId($member);
    $form=$this->createForm(InvoiceType::class, $invoices);
}
```

You are continually overwriting the `$form` value every single time through your loop, so not only can you only handle the last entry, it is the only one that will show up.

I have come across this situation before but it was usually just to delete a single record.  If you are fine with displaying all the forms at once but only updating one member at a time, you can generate a single form for each member (like you are doing now), and then add it to a forms array that you pass to your template.  So your code would now look like:

```
$forms = array();

foreach ($members as $member) {
    $invoices = new Invoice();
    $invoices->setMemberId($member);
    $forms[] = $this->createForm(InvoiceType::class, $invoices)->createView();
}

//...

return $this->render('admin/batchinvoices.html.twig', array(
    'forms' => $forms,
));
```

Notice that I am calling `->createView()` which is what is acceptable for the Twig template.  Then your twig template is going to look something like this:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously you could change the templating to your liking, or even put the individual form definition in its own template and include that like so:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {{ include('@AppBundle/YourController/batchInvoiceForm.html.twig', {'form': form}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind that doing this would only allow you to update one record at a time, so if you didn't want to refresh the page you would want to create an AJAX request that posts to a separate controller action and handles the modification of results and sending a success/fail response back.  The benefit of doing it this way is that you're not posting heaps of data for all members when you're only modifying a small amount.

It could be simpler to just display all member information and then have an Edit button that takes you to a separate form just for updating that member that would then redirect back to your list after submitting - unless I need on-the-fly or bulk updates I always go for this route.

If you want to update all records at once you will have to use the [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) as Onema said.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) That's very similar to what I ended up doing after sticking with the collectionType (I ended up creating a `BatchInvoice` entity). One question though, I used `$form=$this->createForm(InvoiceBatchType::class, $batch);` (ie no `->createView();`)... so am I right in thinking that the `createview()` means you can loop through creating the html for each $member without needing the `InvoiceBatchType` entity?

Comment: All `createView()` does is take a Symfony form and convert it to a format that Twig will understand when you try to call functions that access it (like `form_start(form)`.  All my example above is doing is taking what you would do for a single form (create it, then get it ready for Twig), and doing it in an array from the loop.